# Material-UI v5 not working styled-components and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use the mui-v5 with styled-components and typescript. However, even after I added the line to my tsconfig:

```
"paths": {
  "@mui/styled-engine": [ "./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine-sc" ]
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Could not find dependency: '@emotion/styled' relative to
> '/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/index.js'

when doing: `import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";`

**I made a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-oskar-g43p2) to show my setup.**

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mind showing the content of your package.json? I have `"@mui/styled-engine-sc` in my deps and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 20):

You need to add `@emotion/styled` and `@emotion/react` to dependencies

Comment: But I thought the whole point of using styled-components was that I don't need emotion

Comment: Yeah I checked this https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/ it says that @emotion/react, @emotion/styled, and styled-components are optional peer dependencies of @mui/material, so you need to install them yourself.

Comment: Those instructions are really confusing. If it's optional doesn't that mean you don't need them?

Comment: Check if this codesandbox is what you are looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-4f88k?file=/src/demo.js

Comment: finally. I've read multi para solutions that didn't fix it. this did, thank you

Comment: in my case I added the bellow config to my webpack config file _italic_ resolve: {
    alias:{
      '@mui/styled-engine': '@mui/styled-engine-sc'
    },
  }, _italic_

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to add `@emotion/styled`. The mui [installation](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) says you can use emotion OR styled-components

I know the instructions are a bit confusing but I just copy/pasted the package.json portion in [mui.com/guides/styled-engine/](https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/) and it worked for me

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.14",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this only works with `yarn`, since "resolutions" is a yarn thing

Comment: Aha! Thanks, it did save my night.

Comment: Thank you! How does one figure this out?