# mui for date picker is not working with styled component

Tags: reactjs, mui-x

I'm trying to use mui/x-date-pickers with styled-components (I am on React Typescript served from vite). I have followed the instructions from here:
[mui-styled-engine](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/)
but it still does not work and I receive the following error:
Could not resolve "@emotion/styled" imported by "@mui/styled-engine"

A solution has been proposed to this thread :
[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223243/material-ui-v5-not-working-styled-components-and-typescript) but it didn't work for me.
I am using pnpm whereas solutions seem to be specific to yarn or npm.

Anyone know what should be done?

EDIT:
I have installed the required dependency @emotion/styled. Now I can used styled-component. However I do not understand as I thought if I want to use styled-component, I do not need to install @emotion/styled.